# NavigationSplitView inside a TabView looks bad

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

[image: screenshot]

Migrating to new `NavigationSplitView`, and the pages are inside a `TabView`, but it looks weird. How to make it normal like the old one?

```
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(users, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { user in
                NavigationLink(user, value: user)
            }
        } detail: {
            if let user = selection {
                Text(user)
            } else {
                Text("Pick a node")
            }
        }
```